# VIew and mark as viewed

Tags: javascript, php, pdo, mysqli

How do I get the result of **stName** from $query into the UPDATE statement's **stName**=?

I want to fetch a random record and mark it as "Y" to show it's already being viewed.

```
$query = $conn_db->prepare('SELECT stName, subject FROM my_db WHERE status = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$array = array('N');
$query->execute($array);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);


$status = 'Y';
$sql = 'UPDATE my_db SET status=? WHERE stName=?';
$q = $conn_db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($status,$result));
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio. But did not work.  $status = 'Y'; $q->execute(array($status, $result['stName']));

Comment: and `$q->execute(array($status, $result[0]["stName"]));`?